# Como iterar sobre 2 arrays simultaneamente?

Tags: javascript, array

Inicialmente tenho esse array de objetos contendo os produtos

```
const carros = [
  {produto: "uno 2022", fabricante: "fiat"},
  {produto: "gol g5", fabricante: "volkswagen"},
  {produto: "onix plus 2022", fabricante: "chevrolet"},
  {produto: "KWID", fabricante: "Renault"},
]
```

e também tenho esse array de objetos com as respectivas imagens de produtos

```
const imagemCarros =  [
  {image: "https://garagem360.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/screen-shot-2018-01-12-at-18-48-30.jpg"},
  {image: "https://static.kbb.com.br/Uploads/ResearchTools/News/1252/c79acb69-85e8-44f8-a373-94864ad5c5c8_1365x1024.jpg"},
  {image: "https://production.autoforce.com/uploads/picture/image/85087142/main_comprar-novo-onix-plus-2021-d602ab18-cada-49e7-a2bf-e270b7f8f3a0_6241cea229.jpg"},
  {image: "https://revistagaragem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/renault-kwid-2022-renovado-2022-1536x864-1-780x470.jpg"},
]
```

Preciso que a cada iteração eu tenha a posição 0 dos arrays **carros** e **imagemCarros**, depois a posição 1, 2 e assim sucessivamente

um exemplo abaixo com a posição 0 dos 2 arrays de objetos

```
{produto: "uno 2022", fabricante: "fiat"}, {image: "https://garagem360.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/screen-shot-2018-01-12-at-18-48-30.jpg"},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua descrição está um pouco confusa, mas ao que tudo indica o que você quer é gerar um novo array a partir do primeiro. Para isso você pode utilizar a função `map`:

```js
const carros = [
  {produto: "uno 2022", fabricante: "fiat"},
  {produto: "gol g5", fabricante: "volkswagen"},
  {produto: "onix plus 2022", fabricante: "chevrolet"},
  {produto: "KWID", fabricante: "Renault"},
];

const imagemCarros =  [
  {image: "https://garagem360.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/screen-shot-2018-01-12-at-18-48-30.jpg"},
  {image: "https://static.kbb.com.br/Uploads/ResearchTools/News/1252/c79acb69-85e8-44f8-a373-94864ad5c5c8_1365x1024.jpg"},
  {image: "https://production.autoforce.com/uploads/picture/image/85087142/main_comprar-novo-onix-plus-2021-d602ab18-cada-49e7-a2bf-e270b7f8f3a0_6241cea229.jpg"},
  {image: "https://revistagaragem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/renault-kwid-2022-renovado-2022-1536x864-1-780x470.jpg"},
];

const juncao = carros.map((carro, indice) => ({ ...carro, ...imagemCarros[indice] } ));

console.log(juncao);
```

---

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
> var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
> // roots é [1, 2, 3], numbers ainda é [1, 4, 9]
> ```

Comment: Era exatamente essa a intenção, muito obrigado